# c# stock object array in other array

Tags: c#, arrays

I do a shop on a game and I want get a specifically array compared with the clicked button.
I have an object like this:

```
public class DressItem
{
    private string text;
    public string Text{
        set{this.text = value;}
        get{return this.text;}
    }

    private string mat;
    public string Mat{
        set{this.mat = value;}
        get{return this.mat;}
    }
}
```

Then in my script I create 3 DressItem item and I fill it with data, but I want one reference DressItem (named partRef) take property of one of previous array:

```
    private DressItem[] pants;
    private DressItem[] body; 
    private DressItem[] head;
    private DressItem[] partRef;
```

How can I put object pants with this property in partRef and access to pants property like pant.text ?

I tried to put the 3 Dressitem in an arraylist and take it after like this:

```
private ArrayList arrayPart = new ArrayList();

arrayPart.Add(head);
arrayPart.Add(body);
arrayPart.Add(pants);

partRef = arrayPart(0) as DressItem;
```

But I have this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'DressItem' to `DressItem[]'

I tested to use a list but i must do a mistake i add my items like this:

```
private List<DressItem> arrayPart = new List<DressItem>(); 
arrayPart.Add(head); 
arrayPart.Add(body);
arrayPart.Add(pants);
```

But i have this error :

> The best overloaded method match for System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(DressItem)' has some invalid arguments.

Comment: What do you think `arrayPart(0)` does to start with? And is there any reason you're not using a `List<T>` and automatically implemented properties? As for the actual question - look at the type of `partRef`. That's an array variable. You're taking a *single* `DressItem` value...

Comment: You can assign `partRef` to another part like this `partRef = body;`. Is this what you are after?

Comment: 1) Use `List<T>`, 2) If you did first then `partRef = arrayPart[0];` is enough

Comment: You defined your `arrayPart` list as a collection of `DressItem`s and now you are trying to add element which is `DressItem[]`. Types do not match.

Comment: Why not `private DressItem partRef;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error: I typed my list as `List<DressItem>` instead of `List<DressItem[]>`, and the same for `partRef`.  This was just a stupid mistake.